# Sails.js - All records destroyed if i give undefined "id"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

```
  // DemoTable with id 999 does not exist       
  DemoTable.findOne(999, function(err, found) {
    DemoTable.destroy(found.id, function(err, destroyed) {
    // destroys the whole DemoTable
    });
  });
```

While i was programming my online game with Sails.js, such result happened me about 10 times in 6 months. Good that this project is not released yet and there was no pain to recreate the DB.

I was doing extra check, like:

```
    DemoTable.findOne(999, function(err, found) {
        if(found === undefined || found.id === undefined) return false;
        DemoTable.destroy(found.id, function(err, destroyed) {
            // does not destroy the whole DemoTable
        });
    });
```

But.. this didnt help anyway, i did an accident once and made a typo, like:

```
    DemoTable.find(999, function(err, found) {
        if(found[0] === undefined || found[0].id === undefined) return false;
        DemoTable.destroy(found.id, function(err, destroyed) {
            // destroyed the whole DemoTable
        });
    });
```

And i already had like 10 players (testers) in my game, now they all deleted.

So, i must solve this once and for ever. 
Is there any possible way to protect my DB from deleting my whole table if i give an undefined value? I am using Sails.js.

*** edit *** my model looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    piece:        { type:'string'  },
    shots:        { type:'text'    },
    from_x:       { type:'integer' },
    to_x:         { type:'integer' },
    from_y:       { type:'integer' },
    to_y:         { type:'integer' },
    duration:     { type:'integer' },
    pawn_id:      { type:'integer' },
    building_id:  { type:'integer' },
    user_id:      { type:'integer' },
    health:       { type:'integer' },
    level:        { type:'integer' },
    fighting:     { type:'string'  },
    chess:        { type:'string'  },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'datetime',
      columnName: 'createdat'
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'datetime',
      columnName: 'updatedat'
    },

    toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj._csrf;
        return obj;
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy: function(criteria, cb) {
    if (!criteria) {
      return cb(new Error('Empty criteria'));
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `beforeDestroy` in DemoTable.js model ([Doc](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks#?callbacks-on-destroy)).
Something like this:

```
beforeDestroy: function(criteria, cb) {
  if (!criteria) {
    return cb(new Error('Empty criteria'));
  } else { // Added else part
    return cb();
  }
}
```

Also, it would be better to handle `err` first in callbacks. Like:

```
DemoTable.findOne(999, function(err, found) {
    if(err) { // Error handling if-block
      // Handle error as you like
      return false;
    }
    if(found === undefined || found.id === undefined) return false;
    DemoTable.destroy(found.id, function(err, destroyed) {
        // does not destroy the whole DemoTable
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm it doesn't work. I did as in example, added it under attributes like in Docs, but if i try to destroy, the item is not destroyed, i get only undefined callback, no error, no result, the destruction doesn't pass over.

Comment: Lifecycle callback functions are **not** under `attributes` in model. Please check indentation [closely](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/lifecycle-callbacks#?example)

Comment: I have tried it after attributes also, in the same model. But it doest not work.. My model does not create nor destroy anything then.

Comment: With beforedestroy please

Comment: Sry for long response. Edited my question now with beforedestroy